# How do I find a list of all CocoaPods libraries and what they do?

Tags: cocoapods

I'm building a few different apps and am specifically looking for one that shakes the phone but I'm interested to see all the other capabilities. I'm  looking for a full list of all current CocoaPods. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One tool is `pod search QUERY`:

```
 $ pod search --help
Usage:

    $ pod search QUERY

      Searches for pods, ignoring case, whose name, summary, description, or authors
      match `QUERY`. If the `--simple` option is specified, this will only search in
      the names of the pods.

Options:

    --regex      Interpret the `QUERY` as a regular expression
    --simple     Search only by name
    --stats      Show additional stats (like GitHub watchers and forks)
    --web        Searches on cocoapods.org
    --ios        Restricts the search to Pods supported on iOS
    --osx        Restricts the search to Pods supported on macOS
    --watchos    Restricts the search to Pods supported on watchOS
    --tvos       Restricts the search to Pods supported on tvOS
    --no-pager   Do not pipe search results into a pager
    --verbose    Show more debugging information
    --no-ansi    Show output without ANSI codes
    --help       Show help banner of specified command
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul! I really appreciate your reply.